# How do I create homebrew bottle for old version on a new macOS version?

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to cause a bottle of zsh 5.1.1 to be created for Sierra because zsh 5.2 has a pretty bad bug that breaks certain functionality.

Sierra comes with zsh 5.2 which is broken for multibyte bindkey keystrokes (see: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg01400.html). I've managed to get 5.1.1 to build from source on one machine but for broader distribution a Sierra bottle of zsh 5.1.1 would be much better until a new release of zsh comes out.

The bug not only prevents binding of utf-8 multibyte ascii characters (I use a lot of Option key combos) but blocks other characters from even being typed if they have the same initial byte.

I think this is the last version of the zsh recipe before the bug comes into play: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/1a4461ad2a0f1bc7074d9817db059147a31eeee6/Formula/zsh.rb

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I create homebrew bottle for old version on a new macOS version?

I've successfully build a zsh 5.1.1 bottle on macOS Sierra. Here is how:

First you need to download all commits from the homebrew-core repository because by defaut it's a shallow repository (not all commits are present).

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git fetch --unshallow
```

You then have to select the last commit of zsh 5.1.1 with

```
brew log zsh
```

Here, it's the commit `1a4461ad2a0f1bc7074d9817d`, checkout the zsh formula for this commit

```
git checkout 1a4461ad2a0f1bc7074d9817d -- Formula/zsh.rb
```

Install zsh with `--build-bottle`

```
brew install --build-bottle zsh
```

and build the bottle

```
brew bottle zsh
```

**You then obtain the bottle file** `zsh-5.1.1.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz`

Don't forget to restore the original state of `zsh.rb` with

```
git checkout -- Formula/zsh.rb
```

For installing the bottle, just copy it in `/usr/local/Cellar`, extract it with

```
tar xzvf zsh-5.1.1.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
```

and link it with

```
brew link zsh
```

**== Edit to answer the OP comment ==**

Official homebrew bottles are stored in bintray.com. Bintray is a distribution platform with REST api. When you launch `brew install`, it first check if there is a bottle there. The zsh 5.1.1 bottles are stored in : https://bintray.com/homebrew/bottles/zsh/5.1.1#files. As you can see there is a version for yosemite, mavericks and el capitan, but no version for sierra. You could ask on github to put the zsh-5.1.1 sierra bottle there.

Comment: How would this bottle be published for other users? I can build form source for my machine, the intent of building a bottle is for other users to be able to get the good version of zsh without having to build from source.

Comment: @Mike I've modified my answer to take the question in your comment into account.

Comment: Instead of tar'ing directly, you can `brew install zsh-5.1.1.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz` (or any direct path) since sometime semi-recently.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old issue, but for new comers, <del>I've published an automated build workflow to create and publish bottles for your taps with Azure Pipelines & Bintray.</del>

<del>You can find more information here:</del>

> <del>https://github.com/ladislas/homebrew-greetings</del>

And a real life example is the osx-cross/avr tap that I maintain that now offers bottles for all the formulae including all the versions of avr-gcc from 9.1.0 to 4.x.x.

> https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr/

**EDIT** (2021/03/15) - Homebrew has greatly improved support for custom taps' bottles see:

> [Homebrew tap with bottles uploaded to GitHub Releases](https://brew.sh/2020/11/18/homebrew-tap-with-bottles-uploaded-to-github-releases/)

osx-cross/avr now makes full use of this with Github Actions, you can look into [`.github/workflows`](https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr/tree/master/.github/workflows) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a useful blog post by one of the homebrew maintainers on maintaining your own repository with bottles:

https://jonathanchang.org/blog/maintain-your-own-homebrew-repository-with-binary-bottles/

As you can see from the section below, creating bottles for other macOS versions is as simple as modifying a `.json` file (once the other setup has been done):

https://jonathanchang.org/blog/maintain-your-own-homebrew-repository-with-binary-bottles/#bottling-for-multiple-systems